# Delete a line from a csv file c++

Tags: c++, vector, struct, file-io

Here I have a file that reading in to a vector

```
typedef struct contacts 
{
    string name;   //{jhonathan , anderson , felicia}
    string nickName; //{jhonny  , andy , felic}
    string phoneNumber; // {13453514 ,148039 , 328490}
    string carrier;  // {atandt , coolmobiles , atandt }
    string address; // {1bcd , gfhs ,jhtd }

} contactDetails;

vector <contactDetails> proContactFile;
```

I want to let user to delete a contact record from the file.For this I wrote a code.But from the code that i've written it deletes all the contact details from the file.But what I want here is when a user types a `name` then the program should delete only the `name` and the relevent `nickname,carrier,phone number` and `address` belongs to that name.Here is the code that i've written

```
    string readString, selectContact;
    cout << "Enter the name you want to delete" << endl;
    cin >> selectContact;
    ifstream fin;
    fin.open(contactsFile); 
    if (!fin.is_open())
    {
        cout << "Unable to open Contacts.csv, please make sure file exists!" << endl;
    }
   
    ofstream fout;
    fout.open("temp.csv" , ios::out);

    while (getline(fin, readString))
    {
        if (((readString = readString.find(selectContact), 0)) == 0)
        {
            fout << readString  <<',' << "\n";
            
        }
        cout << "Deleted Successfully" << endl;
        showTableContacts();
    }
    if (((readString = readString.find(selectContact), 0) != 0))
    {
        cout << "\n" << selectContact << " not found" << endl;
    }
   
    fout.close();
    fin.close();
    remove("Contact.csv");//Deletes contacts.csv file
    rename("temp.csv" , "Contact.csv");//Rename temp file as Contacts.csv
}
```

Comment: I'm surprised `readString = readString.find` compiles, it almost certainly doesn't do what you think it does

Comment: `string::find()` returns a `size_t`.    So `if (((readString = readString.find(selectContact), 0)) == 0)`  does not do what you think it does.   Also, when doing file operations, your code continues on some errors - which means it will remove the original `Contact.csv` and replace it with whatever was output to `temp.csv` before the error.

Comment: @Peter So please could you help me with a better way?

Comment: straightforward way to do this: define << and >> operators (read\write for iostream) for your struct contacts, read file into vector via std::copy, use std::remove_if and std::erase to remove elements from vector, write vector into file using std::copy again

Answer (score 0):

```
if (((readString = readString.find(selectContact), 0)) == 0)
```

This line has several issues.

1. readString.find(selectContact) returns the index of the match, or string::npos if it's not found.  Checking that it is an exact match at position 0 is ok, technically, however, in your case if your string is "abcdefg" and you search for "abc" it will also match at position 0 when it shouldn't.  You need to ensure the entire field matches, not just the first characters of it.  (Find the first ',' in your line then ensure that all the bytes from the beginning up to the comma match your contact.)
2. Next consider this part:

   readString = readString.find(selectContact)

You are assigning the result of the find to your string.  That is, if find() returns 3, you will assign 3 to your string, which is interpreted as an ASCII character, and now your readString contains a single byte with junk in it.  (In ASCII, 'A' is 65, etc)

So now your string is obliterated, and the index of your match is the contents, in the first byte (if the value is in range, or undefined behavior if it overflows.)

3. Code of this form:

   if (xxx, 0)

is utilizing the *comma operator*, which sequences expressions by evaluating them from left to right, applying side effects (but throwing away the results) and the full expression evaluates to the value of the rightmost expression.  Whatever xxx does (in your case, xxx is the code in step 2 above, obliterating your string) its return value is discarded and this whole expression evaluates to 0, which converts to a bool as *false*.  Every time.   (1,2,3) evaluates to 3, etc.

Therefore:

```
(readString = readString.find(selectContact), 0)
```

**always** evaluates to 0.  And

```
if (((readString = readString.find(selectContact), 0)) == 0)
```

always obliterates your string, then tests if 0==0 which is always true.

Also, you almost never want to delete your input files.  Rewriting them is dangerous enough, but you must be absolutely sure that everything succeeded before doing so; otherwise your program can end up causing a lot of pain if it deletes the input file and nothing else.